# How to access Hololens camera bytes to video stream

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

I will make a video stream from hololens camera to server through mqtt . So, I have to get bytes from camera buffer, I don't want to record anything, I just want to access what user see in that moment. I couldn't find the way to do it with mixed reality capture.

Answer (score 0):

On HoloLens 2, you can get the video stream directly via [Mixed reality capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/mixed-reality-capture-overview) or engine-specific method, like **WebCamTexture** in Unity. If this is not what you want, please describe the scenario and refine your question.

Comment: I can't find a documentation on midex reality capture. I mean I don't want to record anything. I just need to get what users see and send that through mqtt. Mqtt thing is done. However, I need to access camera buffer I assume.

Comment: There is no way to catch the byte directly. But you can convert the captured stream or file to the type you want. MRC can call in the application and you can use the captured content in the application without storage to the device, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/capture-photos-and-video-with-cameracaptureui. For more information, you can also refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/basic-photo-video-and-audio-capture-with-mediacapture.

Comment: If you want something like real-time communication, you can refer to this sample - https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/SimpleCommunication.